# Solve the vector cross product equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cross-product

Consider the vector equation $a \times x = b$ in $\Bbb R^3$ , where $a\ne0$.

Show that $$x = \frac{b\times a}{|a|^2} + ka$$

is the solution to the equation for any scalar $k$

i really dont know where to start , i really appreciate any help

Comment: You should write $ka$ instead of $k \cdot a$ to avoid confusion with the dot product.

Answer (score 3):

For any constant $\lambda$, $a \times (x - \lambda a) = a\times x = b$  and hence $x-\lambda a$ also satisfies the given condition. Now,
\begin{align*}
a \times (a \times x) = (a \cdot x ) a - (a \cdot a) x = a \times b
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
x = \frac{b \times a}{|a|^2} + \frac{a \cdot x}{|a|^2} a
\end{align*}
For an arbitrary constant $k$ apply the above argument to $x - \left(\frac{a\cdot x - k }{|a|^2} \right)a$
to get $x = \frac{b \times a}{|a|^2} + ka$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $a,b$ are linear independent. Let $R$ be a rotation such that $Ra=k_1e_1,Rb=k_2e_2+k_3e_3$, where $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are standard base of $R^3$ and $k_1,k_2$ are scalars and $k_1\neq0,k_2\neq0$. By [the property of cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) , one has
$$ R(a\times b)=Ra\times Rb=k_1e_1\times (k_2e_2+k_3e_3)=k_1k_2e_3-k_1k_3e_1$$
and hence
$$ R^{-1}(k_2e_3-k_3e_1)=\frac{1}{k_1}a\times b. $$
From $a\times x=b$, one has
$$ R(a\times x)=Rb.$$
 one obtains
$$ (Ra)\times (Rx)=Rb$$
or
$$ k_1e_1\times (Rx)=k_2e_2. $$
Writing $Rx=c_1e_1+c_2e_2+c_3e_3$, one has
$$ k_1e_1\times (c_1e_1+c_2e_2+c_3e_3)=k_2e_2+k_3e_3$$
or
$$ k_1c_2e_3-k_1c_3e_2=k_2e_2+k_3e_3 $$
So 
$$ c_2=\frac{k_3}{k_1},c_3=-\frac{k_2}{k_1}. $$
and henceforth
$$ x=R^{-1}(c_1e_1+c_2e_2+c_3e_3)=c_1R^{-1}e_1+R^{-1}(c_2e_2+c_3e_3)=c_1a+\frac{1}{k_1^2}a\times b=c_1a+\frac{1}{\|a\|^2}a\times b. $$

Comment: First, I believe the fifth equation from the top must be $k_1e_1 \times (Rx) =  k_2e_2+k_3e_3$. Second, as a newcomer to the area let me tell you, your derivation looks so cool to me! Third, having put a lot of thought into it, I managed to understand your derivation. One thing I still don't get is how would one think to arrive at the idea to introduce a rotation matrix and assume the expressions for $Ra$, $Rb$, $Rx$ that you assumed. If you could clarify me on that, I'll greatly appreciate that.

Comment: The reason to use a rotation matrix is to make the representation of $x$ a little bit simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you set $$a = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\a_2 \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix} \quad b = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\b_2 \\ b_3 \end{pmatrix}$$ you can write all the operations on the 3 components, and verify the given relation.

Another way of starting  is to substitute the given $x$ in $a \times x$, and then use the properties of the cross product (linearity etc) to simplify the equation, and see if you get what you want.

Let $x$ be a solution of the equation.
$$a \times x = b \Rightarrow a\cdot(a\times x)= x\cdot (a \times a)=0 = (a\cdot b)$$
In this case, if there is a solution that verifies the relation, necessarly, $a \cdot b = 0$. 
Now, let us assume that $a \cdot b = 0$.
$$a \times (b \times a) = b(a\cdot a) - a (a \cdot b) = b ||a||^2$$

Now, you can continue from here

Comment: i tried to guess the general solution to be x = ka + c , where a and c is linearly independent. substituting to a × x = b , I get a × c = b, doing a x on both sides

Comment: i tried to guess the general solution to be x = ka + c , where a and c is linearly independent. substituting x = ka + c to a × x = b , I get a × c = b because a × a = 0, doing a ×  on both sides leads to a × ( a × c) = a × b . Then by triple cross product I get  (a . c) × (a) - (a . a) × c = a × b . So now I get stucked, if (a . c) = 0, then i get my desired result c = (b × a ) / a^2 . but i have no idea how to prove (a . c) = 0 . I only know that a and c are linearly independent but it does not imply they are orthogonal ? I really appreciate any help

Comment: I'll complete my answer